# How to extract a list of indices based on a date range match in Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have a column with random date values in random order.
I want to extract the indices of any date match which fall between a date range.

I cannot use any sort or filter, the date values should be at its index always.
I am able to extract Indices based on a Date Value but not a range.
Dates are in the format MM/DD/YYYY.

Data Example and Expected Result in Column D:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dates | Start Range | End Range | Indices |
| 11/02/2021 | 11/02/2021 | 11/25/2021 | 1 |
| 10/22/2021 |  |  | 3 |
| 11/22/2021 |  |  | 5 |
| 09/02/2021 |  |  | 6 |
| 11/15/2021 |  |  | #NA |
| 11/02/2021 |  |  | #NA |

Comment: What version of excel do you have and is this the end or are you going to be using these indices in the INDEX formula to return actual data?

Comment: Excel Version: 2110.
Yes, this is the end, I want the indices as the final result.

Comment: Then you have Office 365 and can use the FILTER formula, have you tried that?

Comment: Filter will remove other rows I believe.
Moreover, I want to use formula instead of mouse clicking or any other UI interaction.

Comment: Not the filter on the data tab.  The FILTER formula, ie: `=FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A7)),(A2:A7>=B2)*(A2:A7<=C2),"")` which will spill the results.

Comment: This works as expected! Thank you!
@ScottCraner